# Port forwarding for RStudio Server

Tags: network-manager, iptables, ip, network-bridge, rstudio

I have installed RStudio Server on my PC. Normaly i could have access to RStudio via web with my IP address and port 8787. But my PC is connected to the Internet trough router and  it does not work in that way. I know i have to forward this port but i have completly no idea how to do it. 
Could anybody help my problem?

Comment: You will need to refer to your router's documentation